# Show read it later list in new firefox tabs

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, readitlater

I would like my "Read it Later" reading list to show whenever I open a new firefox tab.  How can I do this?

EDIT:

I would prefer not to use their webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Install [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/777/) and then set your homepage to `http://readitlaterlist.com/unread`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if I don't use their web service?